# Bi-dimensional search with Excel

Tags: excel, algorithm, search, multidimensional-array

Please take a look at the table below:

[image: Table]

I would like to search the left column name (6 in this example) based on two parameters: Top column name (E in this example) and a number (3 in this example).

How can I perform a bi-dimensional search with Excel?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=INDEX(A3:A12,MATCH(M2,INDEX(B3:I12,0,MATCH(L2,B2:I2,0)),0))
```

[image]